# .NET Release code very slow when running a method for the first time. How to fix it withough NGen?

Tags: c#, performance, visual-studio-2012

I have deployed a application in release mode (x64) which I expected to be fast, and I noticed that there is a severe slowdown whenever a new method, or set of methods is executed for the first time.
When I say severe I mean 100-200 ms to execute the first time and it takes well under 1 ms after that.

From what I found, this seems to be due to the JIT compiler which is supposed to compile methods the first time they are run. I expected some delay from this, but 100 ms is a disastrous delay in the middle of execution.

I know about NGen, but NGen needs to be done at install time on the machine. The machines this is for all have limited user rights and cannot install anything. The app is deployed as an executable and reference DLLs. I think that is why I could never get NGen to work.

Is there any way to make the JIT to compile every method at start up?

I though of creating dummy variables and adding a start-up routine that would do nothing but run every method once so it can be what when start-up completes. Would that be sufficient to force a compile or does every code path of a method need to be executed separately.

Comment: you won't really find a way around using ngen for this i'm afraid.

Comment: So what about calling the methods with an optional dummy variable to force compiling. At start-up I call every needed method with a dummy int variable set to 1. It compiles the method, runs any other sub-methods and returns.

Comment: That would be extremely bad practise to be honest, and I would not recommend!

Comment: The top of every method would be if (dummy != 1) initialize, else continue.  The idea is that this one if statement, even on every method is cheap if I can avoid the JITng delays. Is there a better way?

Comment: @MichaelElkin You can do that. But that would be an awful task wouldn't it? The cleanest solution to your problem really is using ngen. I think your best option is finding a way how to get ngen run with your project instead of trying a weird hack around the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wow. Such delays are unusual for the JIT. Profile your app to *make sure* the bottleneck is the JIT.

Now, if it's really the JIT, here's a much better method than adding a dummy argument everywhere:

Use [`RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0bt50792(v=vs.110).aspx) on each non-generic method. This function will force the JIT to process it.

You can also use [`RunClassConstructor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.runtimehelpers.runclassconstructor(v=vs.110).aspx) method on each class to... well, run their static constructors.

Here's some (totally untested) code:

```
foreach (var type in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes())
{
    if (type.IsGenericTypeDefinition || type.IsInterface)
        continue;

    RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor(type.TypeHandle);

    foreach (var method in type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly))
        RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod(method.MethodHandle);
}
```

Comment: I deployed my method with a hand-full of class objects and methods initialized. It added about 500 ms to the start-up, but the delays I was referring to are completely gone.

Comment: With your code will it initialize all methods, including the ones inside objects? As I understand it I need to first initialize all the classes first then the methods. It is a more complete and simple solution and I will test how it is working.

Comment: Also, I have used the VS2012 performance profiler. But for me it gives me which functions are called most often, but not which functions take the longest and it never showed me any JIT delays. Then again I am no expert at reading the output. It did tell me that the GUI was killing performance before I put it on a separate thread and it showed me some unnecessary conversions that I was doing from old code.

Comment: Try [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653). It can show you some JIT stats for your process (on the *.NET Performance* tab), including % time spent in JIT, and number of methods JITted. Yes, my code should initialize all non-generic methods. If you want to avoid a noticeable additional startup cost, you can try running the initialization code from a background thread.

Comment: Your solution works perfectly and is very thorough. It takes a little longer, but now I don't need to worry about any other methods which I was with my code. I will do more testing regarding the best place to run it, or even in another thread as you said and post my results.

Comment: I found that the best place for code is in the Program.cs file before creating the main form. I measured that it takes just under 500 ms to run the entire process, however, I can hardly notice any start-up delays, I think because other start-up procedures, such as creating the form and others that occur when the app is loaded are faster since everything is JIT'd already.

Answer (score 0):

NGen should be run on each machine at install time.  Make it part of your install process.  That will compile for the relevant architecture.

If your delay is indeed due to JITting, this should solve it.  Profile your application to be sure.

Comment: The target machines are running will limited user privileges so they cannot install anything at all. The app is deployed as the executable and any needed reference DLLs which run fine. I guess that is why NGen  never worked on these machines. I will edit the question to explain why NGen is not an option.

Comment: Working with those constraints will make this much harder.  MSI installers can be pushed to client machines with group policy.

Comment: I have no control over user policy at the firm, which are quite strict, and the approvals for such deployments would take a while if it ever gets approved. That is why I am looking for other solutions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My first solution was to manually create dummy instances of classes and then call the methods with an optional dummy bool variable which would be false by default. This worked but required adding this dummy to every method which is crude and time consuming.

Lucas Trzesniewski's answer is far more through as it prepares all classes and all methods in the code and it does not require any changes to any of my code so it is much easier to implement.
The only cost is that by being so thorough it takes longer to complete at about .5 to 1.5 seconds or maybe .5 to 1 second longer than my selective start-up. More than worth it in my case to ensure no delays happen in code.

There was no noticeable spike in memory or CPU usage other than the initial start-up, and memory usage actually slightly decreased, possibly because all code is now complied and optimized.