# Measure Compilation Time For Each Method On C#

Tags: c#, performance, interceptor

We are going to create a web service that performance is so important for us. Therefore we decided measure compilation time of each method.

We want to intercept each method and log the compilation time. But we do not want to change the code for release. Therefore how can we make this interceptor run only on debug mode?

Comment: Why don't you [pre-JIT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25290178/3764814) everything?

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski That doesn't makes much sense. Why don't you NGgen instead of doing the same thing over and over?

Comment: @Sriram because it doesn't require a post-install step like NGen does. You get easier deployment. But I agree that NGen is the better option if you're ok with the maintenance costs.

Comment: JIT-compilation in the CLR happens only once per method (unlike Java HotSpot). And since you have a web service, it only starts up once, practically. For these reasons, I don't think JIT-compilation overhead will matter in this scenario, but I could be wrong.

Comment: With Ngen can we measure compile time of private methods also?

Comment: I highly doubt that measuring the compilation time of anything will help you anywhere, in any way whatsoever.

Comment: We just want to be sure about service performance before the production version.

Comment: Think about **runtime** performance. Forget **compile time**

Comment: @cCcik NGen compiles everything up front, and pre-JIT compiles everything at startup. In each case there's no more runtime overhead, **except** for generic methods, which should be minoritary anyway.

Comment: If at all you want to measure, you can use built in PerformanceCounter which have the counter for JIT time

Answer (score 0):

Here is the interceptor which calculates each method in a class. (It uses log4net)

```
internal class DurationCalculatorAspect : IMessageSink
{
   public bool ExceptionHandlingEnabled { get; set; }

    internal DurationCalculatorAspect(IMessageSink next,bool exceptionHandlingEnabled)
    {
        m_next = next;
        ExceptionHandlingEnabled = exceptionHandlingEnabled;
    }

    private IMessageSink m_next;
    #region IMessageSink implementation
    public IMessageSink NextSink
    {

        get { return m_next; }
    }

    public IMessage SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)
    {
        var typeResolver = ((System.Type[])(((System.Collections.ArrayList)msg.Properties.Values)[2]));
        var typeName = "void";
        if(typeResolver.Count()!=0)
        {
            typeName = typeResolver[0].FullName;
        }

        var argsString = "";
        var argArray =(object[])((System.Collections.ArrayList)msg.Properties.Values)[4];
        for (int i = 0;i<argArray.Length;i++)
        {
            argsString+=(i+1).ToString() + ". Object : " +argArray[i];
        }
        Logger.GetLogger().Debug("MethodName : "+((System.Collections.ArrayList)msg.Properties.Values)[1]+"\r\n"+
            "TypeName: " + typeName + "\r\n" + "Args : " + argsString
            );
        var date1 = DateTime.Now;


      var  returnMethod =
        m_next.SyncProcessMessage(msg);

        var returnMessage = ((IMethodReturnMessage)returnMethod);

        var date2 = DateTime.Now;
        Logger.GetLogger().Debug("MethodName : " + returnMessage.MethodName + "Duration : " + date2.Subtract(date1).TotalMilliseconds + " .ms"+"\r\n"+
            "TypeName: " + typeName + "\r\nReturned : " +returnMessage.ReturnValue);

        if (returnMessage.Exception != null)
        {
            Logger.GetLogger().Fatal("Exception : " + returnMessage.Exception.Data + " InnerException : " + returnMessage.Exception.InnerException);
            if (ExceptionHandlingEnabled)
            {
                return new ReturnMessage(null, null);
            }
        }


        return returnMethod;
    }

    public IMessageCtrl AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg,
    IMessageSink replySink)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }

    #endregion //IMessageSink implementation

}

public class DurationCalculatorInterceptorProperty : IContextProperty,
IContributeObjectSink
{
    public bool ExceptionHandlingEnabled { get; set; }

    public DurationCalculatorInterceptorProperty(bool exceptionHandlingEnabled)
    {
        ExceptionHandlingEnabled = exceptionHandlingEnabled;
    }

    #region IContributeObjectSink implementation
    public IMessageSink GetObjectSink(MarshalByRefObject o,
    IMessageSink next)
    {
        return new DurationCalculatorAspect(next,ExceptionHandlingEnabled);
    }
    #endregion // IContributeObjectSink implementation

    #region IContextProperty implementation
    // Implement Name, Freeze, IsNewContextOK
    #endregion //IContextProperty implementation


    public void Freeze(Context newContext)
    {
    }

    public bool IsNewContextOK(Context newCtx)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return ""; }
    }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class DurationCalculatorInterceptorAttribute : ContextAttribute
{
    public bool ExceptionHandlingEnabled { get; set; }

    public DurationCalculatorInterceptorAttribute(bool exceptionHandlingEnabled) : base("Security")
    {
        ExceptionHandlingEnabled = exceptionHandlingEnabled;
    }

    public override void GetPropertiesForNewContext(
    IConstructionCallMessage ccm)
    {
        ccm.ContextProperties.Add(new DurationCalculatorInterceptorProperty(ExceptionHandlingEnabled));

    }
}
```

Two classes which uses interception to log duration and one for handling exceptions is given below. It is strange but handling exceptions with this interceptor is 28 times faster. But it is only useful for only logging exceptions. Also do not forget your class to inherit ContextBoundObject.

```
[DurationCalculatorInterceptor(false)]
public class WithoutExceptionHandling : ContextBoundObject
{
    public void DivideYeahWithoutExceptionHandling()
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                var x = 2;
                var y = 1;

                var z = x / (y - 1);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {


            }
        }

    }
}
[DurationCalculatorInterceptor(true)]
public class WithExceptionHandling : ContextBoundObject
{
    public void DivideYeahWithExceptionHandling()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            var x = 2;
            var y = 1;
            var z = x / (y - 1);
        }
    }
}
```